# Cannot access file because it is being used by another process : DFSR

Tags: c#, .net, sdl, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I’m getting an error with my single thread C# 4.0 desktop application. 
When I try to save a file, I’m getting the following error :

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.

We have turned off DFSR in order to test, and the problem was solved.

My application is using SDL's dll (Trados Studio) and the error also occurs in Trados Studio.

**So my question is:** Is there something that I can do with DFSR to solve my issue or is this something related to the application itself?

EDIT

```
var project = new FileBasedProject(this.GetInfoForTemplateProject(projectName, projectFolder, projectDueDate), template);

/* ... */

project.GetTranslationProviderConfiguration();
project.UpdateTranslationProviderConfiguration(tmConfig);

project.Save();
```

My problem occurs at project.Save(). FileBasedProject is a class of the third party librairy (SDL Trados). The file that I'm accessing is a project file (.sdlproj)

Comment: Could you show the code that is accessing the file?

Comment: I edited my question